# Elasticsearch wildcard, regexp, match_phrase, prefix query returning wrong results

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, wildcard, analyzer, match-phrase

I have just started using Elasticsearch, version 7.5.1.

I want to query results which start with a particular word fragment.
For example **tho*** should return data containing:

> thought, Thomson, those, etc.

I tried with -

1. Regexp

```
[{'regexp':{'f1':'tho.*'}},{'regexp':{'f2':'tho.*'}}]
```

2. Wildcard

```
[{'wildcard':{'f1':'tho*'}},{'wildcard':{'f2':'tho*'}}]
```

3. Prefix

```
[{'prefix':{'f1':'tho'}},{'prefix':{'f2':'tho'}}]
```

3. match_phrase

```
'multi_match': {'query': 'tho', 'fields':[f1,f2,f3], 'type':phrase}
# also tried with type phrase_prefix
```

All those are returning correct results, but they all also return the word *method*.

Similarly **cat*** is returning the word *communication*.

What I am doing wrong? Is this something related to **analyzer**?

- Edit -
  Here is the field mapping -

```
'f1': {
                'full_name': 'f1',
                'mapping': {
                    'f1': {
                        'type': 'text',
                        'analyzer': 'some_analyzer',
                        'index_phrases': true
                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided any index mapping of yours and as mentioned you are getting `method` also in the search result. I think that there is some issue with the analyzer that you have set.

**One possibility is that you have set [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), that tokenizes the words, and produce token of `tho` (since all the words have `tho` present in them)**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "f1": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "f1": "method"
}
{
  "f1": "thought"
}
{
  "f1": "Thomson"
}
{
  "f1": "those"
}
```

**Search Query using Wildcard Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "f1": {
        "value": "tho*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query using Prefix Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "f1": {
        "value": "tho"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query using Regexp query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "f1": {
        "value": "tho.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search QUery using match phrase prefix query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "f1": {
        "query": "tho"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result for all the above 4 queries are**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67673694",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2039728,
        "_source": {
          "f1": "thought"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67673694",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.2039728,
        "_source": {
          "f1": "Thomson"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67673694",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.2039728,
        "_source": {
          "f1": "those"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I have already the mapping type text - 
`'f1': {'full_name': 'f1','mapping': {'f1': {'type': 'text','analyzer': 'some_analyzer','index_phrases': True}}}`

Comment: @Aditya you are using some `analyzer` also ? Can you please share the definition of that analyzer ?

Comment: @Aditya can you please share your index settings as well ?

Comment: It is a smartcn analyzer(zh analyzer), that's only I can share.